# Very easy question : Sample Variance

Tags: variance, sample

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the standard error work?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33547/how-does-the-standard-error-work)

Let's say I have an unbiased estimator, which is the sample mean, to estimate $\theta$. When can you say that $$VAR[\overline{X}] = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} $$
?

If so yes, if not: when is this true?

Comment: What does $\theta$ have to do with this question? Or do you mean $\sigma$?

Comment: So long as you have an IID sample, this is always the variance of $\bar{X}$ (assuming the variance of each draw is $\sigma^2$).

Comment: Ah, I saw this https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/167

I understand it completely now :)